# How to include un-matched documents in the mongodb aggregation output?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wrote below aggregation which is unwinding an array within a collection and then checking if each unwound document matches any element in the given array of object id's. While projecting, the resultant collection passes through condition to filter it further.

```
  db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { $unwind: { 
          path: "$field5", 
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
        } 
    },
    { $match: {  field5: { $in: 

       [
          ObjectId("id1"),
          ObjectId("id2"),
          ObjectId("id3")
      ]

        } } },
    { $project: { 
        _id: 0,
        field0: "$field0",
        field1: "$field1",
        field2: "$field2",
        customField: { 
            $or:[{
                  $and: [ 
                      { /*...some  condition*/ } ,  
                      { /*...some condition*/  }   
                    ],
                },
                { 
                    $and: [ 
                      { /*...some  condition*/ } , 
                      {  /*...some  condition*/ }   
                    ]
              }]
           }
       } 
     }
  ])
```

This works as expected.

**Result**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "field0" : "processing",
    "field5" : ObjectId("id1"),
    "field1" : "val",
    "field2" : "val",
    "customField" : false
}

/* 2 */
{
    "field0" : "processing",
    "field5" : ObjectId("id2"),
    "field1" : "val",
    "field2" : "val",
    "customField" : false
}
```

If i understood it right, $match stage removes unmatched id (say id3). How can i still get it in the final output by creating a separate document with all fields projected for it?.

**What's Expected**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "field0" : "processing",
    "field5" : ObjectId("id1"),
    "field1" : "val",
    "field2" : "val",
    "customField" : false
}

/* 2 */
{
    "field0" : "processing",
    "field5" : ObjectId("id2"),
    "field1" : "val",
    "field2" : "val",
    "customField" : true
}


/* 3 */
/* Note that id3 is unmatched (excluded by $match in result) */
{
    "field0" : "processing",
    "field5" : ObjectId("id3"),
    "field1" : "val",
    "field2" : "val",
    "customField" : true
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is that query really excluding 3rd doc ? As per `$match` it should include it as well !! Anyway do you need matched & unmatched docs in the same output ? If Yes - then what will be the difference between those two types (something like any field that says true of matched docs & false for unmatched )? If no such thing then it's no use of doing `$match`, If that's the case you actually post your original requirement, So that someone can help you on that..

Comment: @whoami Thanks for reply. Apologies, I should have probably explained the use case as well. The collectionName is keeping temporary entries of id's (in field5 which is an array) to be matched. The $match stage compares the unwind documents with the array passed to it to seek matches. This is where i don't see id3 and not sure if it's correct. I would like to retain unmatched value and keep it somewhere. The unmatched value is also not expected to be checked against conditions in the $project so it won't be filtered further and should be included in the final result.

Comment: So all you need is to retain unmatched docs in output, along with that you need to do something more on matched docs ? So do want to get multiple docs returned for every single doc  at the end (As you're doing `$unwind`), if Yes - then it makes sense to unwind else it's not needed (So what you're doing is splitting a single doc into multiple on field5 & categorizing them into matched vs not-matched, end of the day it's same doc with different field5's )?? **Anyhow in your given sample docs & query I think you should be getting doc with `ObjectId("id3")` not sure why you're not getting it**

Comment: @whoami, thanks for reply. For now i am comparing matched results with the temporary entries (field5 array) and adding only missing or unmatched items to it. It may seems a dirty hack but working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that but it is a little bit tricky.

`$facet` will help in achieving that.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
  $facet:{
    "matched":[
      { 
        $unwind:{ 
          path: "$field5", 
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
        } 
      },
      { 
        $match:{  
          field5: {
            $in:
             [
                ObjectId("id1"),
                ObjectId("id2"),
                ObjectId("id3")
             ]
          } 
        } 
      },
      { 
        $project: { 
          _id: 0,
          field0: "$field0",
          field1: "$field1",
          field2: "$field2",
          customField: { 
              $or:[{
                    $and: [ 
                        { /*...some  condition*/ } ,  
                        { /*...some condition*/  }   
                      ],
                  },
                  { 
                      $and: [ 
                        { /*...some  condition*/ } , 
                        {  /*...some  condition*/ }   
                      ]
                }]
             }
         } 
       }
    ],
    "unmatched":[
    { 
      $unwind:{ 
        path: "$field5", 
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
      } 
    },
    { 
      $match:{  
        field5: {
          $nin:
           [
              ObjectId("id1"),
              ObjectId("id2"),
              ObjectId("id3")
           ]
        } 
      } 
    },
    { 
      $project: { 
        _id: 0,
        field0: "$field0",
        field1: "$field1",
        field2: "$field2",
        customField: { 
            $or:[{
                  $and: [ 
                      { /*...some  condition*/ } ,  
                      { /*...some condition*/  }   
                    ],
                },
                { 
                    $and: [ 
                      { /*...some  condition*/ } , 
                      {  /*...some  condition*/ }   
                    ]
              }]
           }
       } 
     }
    ]
  }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "all":{
        $concatArrays:[
          "$matched",
          "$unmatched"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$all"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot:{
      newRoot:"$all"
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Hope this will help your use case.

Also, You can update both facets ("matched" and "unmatched") according to your needs.

you can find more about $facet [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

Comment: $facets looks interesting. I will surely try it. As of now i am comparing matched results with the temporary entries (field5 array) and adding only missing or unmatched items to it. Thank you.

Comment: And one more thing about ```$facet``` is it runs concurrently, i.e; all the stages in the facet will run simultaneously.